# JavaMail Transmission of Large and Binary MIME Messages(rfc3030)

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I need to exchange with one of mail server, using [RFC3030](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3030.txt) for large mime messages.
Original task is: if MIME message size > 80MB, I need to use RFC3030.

How I understand, JavaMail can't do this "from the box"?

Maybe I can create some handler or extension for JavaMail that implement RFC3030?

Please help. I don't know what to do.

Answer (score 0):

A quick look into `SMTPTransport` confirms: Plain old JavaMail does not support BDAT, it will always try to send with  DATA command like this:

```
this.message.writeTo(data(), ignoreList);
finishData();
```

If you're not afraid (and have no legal reason not to) to tinker with core JDK classes, you could override the methods data() and finishData() as they're both protected (source code from [here](https://java.net/projects/javamail/sources/mercurial/content/mail/src/main/java/com/sun/mail/smtp/SMTPTransport.java?rev=328)):

```
/**
* Send the <code>DATA</code> command to the SMTP host and return
* an OutputStream to which the data is to be written.
*
* @since JavaMail 1.4.1
*/
protected OutputStream data() throws MessagingException {
  assert Thread.holdsLock(this);
  issueSendCommand("DATA", 354);
  dataStream = new SMTPOutputStream(serverOutput);
  return dataStream;
}

/**
* Terminate the sent data.
*
* @since JavaMail 1.4.1
*/
protected void finishData() throws IOException, MessagingException {
  assert Thread.holdsLock(this);
  dataStream.ensureAtBOL();
  issueSendCommand(".", 250);
}
```

In order to support [RFC3030](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3030.txt), I'd suggest you start off by buffering the whole message into an `ByteArrayOutputStream` which you'll need to determine the size of the message to be sent. If "small" -> do as `SMTPTransport` would have done. If "big", split the bytes into chunks and send them in `BDAT` style. I'd suggest to end with 0 lentgh `LAST` `BDAT` and code

```
protected void finishData() throws IOException, MessagingException {
  assert Thread.holdsLock(this);
  dataStream.ensureAtBOL();
  issueSendCommand("BDAT 0 LAST", 250);
}
```

**-- EDIT --**

Here's a very unsophisticated first approach, lots of things to do better. Most important a chunking-as-you-go implementation for the `outputStream` sending out chunks of data while the `message.writeTo()` keeps filling it. Filling up a big byte[] just to split it up into chunks later is very, very bad in terms of memory footprint. But it's easier to read that way as all of chunking and sending happens in one place. Please note that this example uses reflection to access `serverOutput` field in Oracle's `SMTPTransport`. So it might break anytime with no warning with any new release of JavaMail. Also my Exception handling does not follow RFC-3030 for now as no RSET is performed if BDAT fails.

```
package de.janschweizer;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;

import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.URLName;

import com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPOutputStream;

public class SMTPTransport extends com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport {

    //We can have our own copy - it's only used in the methods we override anyways.
    private SMTPOutputStream dataStream;

    private ByteArrayOutputStream baos;

    public SMTPTransport(Session session, URLName urlname, String string, boolean bool) {
        super(session, urlname, string, bool);
    }

    public SMTPTransport(Session session, URLName urlname) {
        super(session, urlname);            
    }

    protected OutputStream data() throws MessagingException {
        assert(Thread.holdsLock(this));
        if(!supportsExtension("CHUNKING")) {
            return super.data();
        }
        baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        this.dataStream = new SMTPOutputStream(baos);       
        return this.dataStream;
    }

    protected void finishData() throws IOException, MessagingException {
        assert(Thread.holdsLock(this));
        if(!supportsExtension("CHUNKING")) {
            super.finishData();
            return;
        }
        this.dataStream.ensureAtBOL();
        dataStream.flush();
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new StringReader(new String(baos.toByteArray())));

        try {
            //BAD reflection hack
            Field fServerOutput = com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.class.getDeclaredField("serverOutput");
            fServerOutput.setAccessible(true);
            OutputStream os = (OutputStream)fServerOutput.get(this);

            //Do the Chunky
            ByteArrayOutputStream bchunk = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(bchunk);
            String line = br.readLine();
            int linecount = 0;
            while(line != null) {
                pw.println(line);
                if(++linecount % 5000 == 0) {
                    pw.flush();
                    byte[] chunk = bchunk.toByteArray();
                    sendChunk(os, chunk);
                    bchunk = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    pw = new PrintWriter(bchunk);
                }
                line = br.readLine();
            }
            pw.flush();
            byte[] chunk = bchunk.toByteArray();
            sendLastChunk(os, chunk);           
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new MessagingException("ReflectionError", e);
        }
    }

    private void sendChunk(OutputStream os, byte[] chunk) throws MessagingException, IOException {
        sendCommand("BDAT "+chunk.length);
        os.write(chunk);
        os.flush();     
        int rc = readServerResponse();
        if(rc != 250) {
            throw new MessagingException("Something very wrong");
        }
    }

    private void sendLastChunk(OutputStream os, byte[] chunk) throws MessagingException, IOException {
        sendCommand("BDAT "+chunk.length+" LAST");
        os.write(chunk);
        os.flush();     
        int rc = readServerResponse();
        if(rc != 250) {
            throw new MessagingException("Something very wrong");
        }
    }
}
```

With this META-INF/javamail.providers

```
protocol=smtp; type=transport; class=de.janschweizer.SMTPTransport; vendor=Jan Schweizer;
```

Comment: Yes, that's probably the right approach, although the code should check that the server supports the CHUNKING extension before doing any of this.  Also, you should be able to subclass SMTPTransport, create your own Transport type, package it in your own jar file with a javamail.providers file, and have it work alongside JavaMail without changing JavaMail itself.

Comment: @BillShannon Yes, creating own implementation and subclassing sounds nice. Too bad that all of dataStream, serverOutput and issueSendCommand are private. Short of a full source copy or really bad reflection hacks that's a dead end.

Comment: @BillShannon Scratch that. We'd only need serverOutput anyways. Access to that in a protected way might be nice

Comment: You could use the sendCommand method, but you have to combine the BDAT command with the message data in a single byte array.  You definitely don't want to use SMTPOutputStream because it does dot quoting, which you don't want.  You do need CRLFOutputStream.  And if you wrote your own OutputStream, you could fill a buffer with BDAT and message data, write it using sendCommand, read the response, and continue to the next buffer.  I see that Gmail supports CHUNKING, so this might be a good thing to add to JavaMail.

Comment: yes - sendData sounds nice. Maybe I'll give that a shot on github.

Comment: @BillShannon: sendData appends CRLF - invalid for use with BDAT :-(

Comment: Sigh.  I guess I need to add this to the list of things to consider for the next JavaMail release.

Comment: I've added CHUNKING/BDAT support to JavaMail 1.6.  Let me know if you'd like to test it before it's released.

Comment: @BillShannon From the following comment looks like JM still cannot binary data  /*
   * Use BDAT to send the data in chunks.
   * Note that even though the BDAT command is able to send
   * messages that contain binary data, we can't use it to
   * do that because a) we still need to canonicalize the
   * line terminators for text data, which we can't tell apart
   * from the message content, and b) the message content is
   * encoded before we even know that we can use BDAT.
   */

Comment: Right, the binary data is always going to be encoded.